# Execute row click using listener on primefaces datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Problem is short. I have created a `p:datatable` but within the `p:column` i actually have a `div` element. Unfortunately the datatable should have selectable rows and the div just won't cooperate ;).
So the solution is to call it manually, on the div element there is onclick listener, but how should I call the rowSelection of the datatable? Is there some list of the functions of Primefaces' elements?

the code:

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{rec.friends}" rowKey="#{user.id}" widgetVar="friendscrollist"
        rendered="#{not empty rec.friends}" scrollable="true" rowIndexVar="findex"
        scrollHeight="500" scrollWidth="220" selectionMode="single" selection="#{rec.chosenFriend}" styleClass="friendscroll">
                <p:column width="198" id="friend#{findex}">
    <div class="friendlist" onclick="friendscrollist.clickRow(#{findex})" />
                </p:column>
                <p:ajax update=":leftform" event="rowSelect" />
                <p:ajax update=":leftform" event="rowUnselect" />
</p:dataTable>
```

Of course it is a simplified version, only things u need. So the question is what to call in the **`div onclick?`**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the `<p:dataTable widgetVar>` has `unselectAllRows()` and `selectRow(index)` functions which are exactly what you need.

```
<div onclick="friendscrollist.unselectAllRows(); friendscrollist.selectRow(#{findex})">
```

There's unfortunately no documentation available for those functions, but in Chrome/Firebug you can see a list of all available functions in autocomplete list when you enter `friendscrollist.` in JS console. Below is a screen from Chrome:

[image]

Looking in the JS source code or common sense based on the function name should tell/hint you what those functions do.

---

**Update**: I stand corrected, a few of those functions are actually documented in [PrimeFaces 3.4 User's Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html). They're in the "Client Side API" section of chapter 3.26 "DataTable", on page 146.

Comment: Thank you again! :) You're impossible!

Comment: this is not working with a datatable with pagination enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted solution will work for a single selection table, but won't work for multiple selection.  Another way to solve this problem that should work for both is to use the following instead of `<div>`

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
```

That will render a `<div>` inside your column, and will not interfere with the onclick event processing.

Answer (score 1):

For pagination, you can control rows per page issue by this way:

```
friendscrollist.selectRow(#{rowIndex} - friendscrollist.paginator.getCurrentPage() * friendscrollist.paginator.cfg.rows);
```

Comment: Note also that you need to have rowKey set on the dataTable, and you can deselect all using .unselectAllRows().

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another information for everybody who faces a similar issue with right click or context menu. You cannot capture right click event if you are using `<p:graphicimage>`. Somehow, oncontextmenu event of `<img>` tag is removed in primefaces.

If you want to select the row by right clicking an image content inside a row, you should use  tag and oncontextmenu event.

```
<img src="..." oncontextmenu="dataTable.unselectAllRows();dataTable.selectRow(#{rowIndex});"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If pagination is enabled you can do something like this:

```
onmouseup="friendscrollist.unselectAllRows();friendscrollist.selectRow(#{rowIndex} - friendscrollist.paginator.getCurrentPage() * 15);"
```

When 15 is the number of rows in your Table.

I didn't found a way to get the number of rows programatically...