# p:dataTable: Trigger rowSelect event when click embedded content (image)

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In the example below the rowSelect-event will be triggered if I click a row, but not if clicking the image in the row.

I understand why this happening, but i'm wondering if there is some elegant way to include the subcomponents also (possibly nested subcomponents also)?

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" rows="5"
        selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"
            update=":form" />
        <p:column headerText="Model">
            <p:graphicImage value="myImage.png"
                style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294968/execute-row-click-using-listener-on-primefaces-datatable

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an onclick event on the image:

```
<p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowIndex" widgetVar="scrollist"...

... onclick="scrollist.unselectAllRows(); scrollist.selectRow(#{rowIndex})"
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the embedded content is an image** that will be always displayed in a column (like in the picture below) and you want the image not interfering with the row selection, you can do:

```
<p:column styleClass="my_icon">
```

And create the css class:

```
.my_icon {
   background-image: url("myicon.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

You will get something like this:

[image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

just add the css to embeded img tag:

table tbody td img {
      pointer-events: none;

```
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

}